# Select Range of DocProperty

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have endless Word-Documents, all with the same DocProperty somewhere in it.
Now I have to modify the font style of this specific DocProperty (e.g. make it bold), any other DocProperty has to been skipped.

How do I select this DocProperty with VBA?

I looked into the `ActiveDocument.Range.Fields` collection, but where is the name of the linked DocProperty? I'm only finding the Text, but that is the value of the actual CustomDocProperty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track. In short you want: -

- To look in `Field.Type` for a value of 85 (WdFieldDocProperty)
- Then check the `Field.Code` for the property name/label

A sample of checking a document for it is below with comments to explain what is happening: -

```
Public Sub Sample()
Dim WdDoc   As Word.Document
Dim Fld     As Word.Field

'Connect to the Document
Set WdDoc = ThisDocument

    'Only work if there are fields in the document to begin with
    If WdDoc.Fields.Count > 0 Then

        'Check each field
        For Each Fld In WdDoc.Fields

            'If the type is a DocProperty then we may have a match
            If Fld.Type = wdFieldDocProperty Then

                'If the code contains the name we are after then we have a match!
                If InStr(1, Fld.Code, "Custom1") Then

                    'Select the field
                    Fld.Select

                    'Format the selection
                    Selection.Font.Bold = True

                End If

            End If

        Next

    End If

Set WdDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

As a further tip (if you haven't done it all ready) would be to use the FileScriptingObject to help process all of your documents in one go using a loop. If you do try that and get stuck, start a new question with how far you got and what is not working and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) will help out I'm sure.

Comment: `.Code` ... Who named the "name"-Field `.Code`?! Thanks a lot!